# Loop through strings stored as hash values Perl

Tags: perl

I have created a hash which has following key:value structure.

```
%multifasta = ('sequence1', ACCGTG, 'sequence2' , AGTCGTAGC, 'sequence3' , AGTCGCTAGCATAGCA)
```

where, the ACGT strings are stored as hash values and sequence number is stored as hash keys.

I want to loop through the strings stored as hash values to count the number of A,C,G, and T nucleotide.

What I tried is :

```
while(my($key, $value) = each %multifasta){
    print "$key\n";
    my $len = length($value);
    my $nucl;
    foreach $nucl($value){
        print "$nucl\n";
    }
}
```

but, instead of printing values like this for sequence1 in the `print "$nucl\n";`

```
A
C
C
G
T
G
```

it is printing output like

```
ACCGTG
```

Do I need to convert the values to array and then iterate through array or I can loop through the strings and print individual element of the string?

Comment: Note that you are using barewords as values and with no warnings or strict pragma enabled this is valid, but it is highly discouraged and is unidiomatic. Enabling the  warnings and strict pragmas should be the first thing you do when you begin writing new code. 

Check out this article on barewords : https://perlmaven.com/barewords-in-perl

I would also advise you to read Modern Perl : http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to convert a string into a list of individual characters.  The `split` function with an empty pattern will perform this transformation.

```
...
my @chars = split //, $value;
foreach my $nucl (@chars) {
    print "$nucl\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at

```
perldoc -fsplit
```

You need something like

```
print join("\n", split('',$value));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to [count characters](https://perldoc.pl/perlfaq4#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?), there's no need to split anything:

```
my $a_count = $value =~ tr/A//;
my $c_count = $value =~ tr/C//;
```

etc.